Simulate Random People Walking into a Room
This is a problem I thought of and am trying to figure out.

Suppose there are 100 people: Person1, Person2,... Person100.

A random person is selected and walks into the room.

The next person to walk into the room is randomly selected of the remaining group of people, based on the last person that walked into the room before them.

Individuals having a number closer to the person that just walked in are more likely to be selected. Individuals further away have less probability (the probability distribution does not need to be symmetric)

Once a person has walked into the room, they can not leave


For example, if Person17 walked into the room, then Person18 and Person16 have higher probabilities of being selected next, whereas Person99 has a smaller probability of being selected next. This probability decreases the further you move away from the last person to walk into the room.
Here is a function I wrote to do this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4900283/randomly-ordering-people-walking-into-a-room):
calculate_probability <- function(S, L, x) {
      S <- S[S != L]
      

  if (!(x %in% S)) {
    return(0)
  }
 
  numerator <- 1 / (abs(x - L) + 1)

  denominator <- sum(1 / (abs(S - L) + 1))
  
  probability <- numerator / denominator
  
  return(probability)
}

# sanity check

S <- c(1:10)
L <- 8
x <- 8
probability <- calculate_probability(S, L, x)
print(probability) 

# probabilities sum to 1


S <- c(1:10)
L <- 8

S <- S[S != L]

probabilities <- sapply(S, function(x) calculate_probability(S, L, x))

print(probabilities)
sum(probabilities)

I am now trying to do the following:

Imagine there are 100 people. A randomly selected person walks into the room.
I want to use this function to simulate the other 99 people walking into the room
I want to plot (i.e. ggplot2) the results (i.e. x-axis is the index and the y-axis is the number corresponding to each person)

The final result should contain the list of people in the order they entered the room, e.g. Person1, Person3, Person5, Person8, Person2, etc.
Can someone help me do this?

Write a basic loop that selects one observation and removes it based on some probability vector, just store the one that was removed.
g is a generic function that takes x observations where y was selected previously, and returns probabilities of being selected for the remaining x
You can also weight these probabilities to be stronger or weaker using w
g <- function(x, y, w = 1) {
  # return vector of probabilities for x (excluding y) given y was selected
  # g(1:10, 7)
  y <- which(x %in% y)
  p <- abs(1 / (x - x[y]))[-y]
  (p ^ w) / sum(p)
}

f <- function(x, fun = g, w = 1) {
  # record which of x is selected given probability generating function fun
  # f(1:10)
  s <- function(x, p = NULL) x[sample.int(length(x), 1L, FALSE, p)]
  o <- NULL
  y <- s(x)
  while (length(x) > 1L) {
    o <- c(o, y)
    p <- fun(x, y, w)
    x <- setdiff(x, y)
    y <- s(x, p)
  }
  c(o, y)
}

Here are some examples using different probability functions
set.seed(1)
op <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2), mar = c(5, 5, 2, 2), oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0), pch = 16L)

for (w in c(0, 0.5, 1, 5))
  plot(f(1:100, g, w), type = 'o', ylab = 'ID selected', main = paste('weight: ', w))
title(main = 'prefer close', outer = TRUE)


for (w in -c(0, 1, 5, 10))
  plot(f(1:100, g, w), type = 'o', ylab = 'ID selected', main = paste('weight: ', w))
title(main = 'prefer far', outer = TRUE)


Example using another type of function
h <- function(x, y, w = 1) {
  # h(1:10, 4)
  rev(sort(runif(length(x) - 1))) ^ w
}

for (w in c(0, 1, 5, 10))
  plot(f(1:100, h, w), type = 'o', ylab = 'ID selected', main = paste('weight: ', w))
title(main = 'prefer long waits', outer = TRUE)


And here is how you can use calculate_probability as the probability function
h <- function(x, y, w = 1) {
  # h(1:10, 7)
  x <- setdiff(x, y)
  sapply(x, function(xx) calculate_probability(x, y, xx)) ^ w
}

for (w in c(0, 1, 5, 10))
  plot(f(1:100, h, w), type = 'o', ylab = 'ID selected', main = paste('weight: ', w))
title(main = 'prefer close', outer = TRUE)

par(op)



thanks! what do you think of my answer I wrote below? does it make sense to you?

The last person will be selected with certainty, so your loop can go to (n - 1), not n. Also, S <- S[S != L] should go before you calculate the probabilities because you've already selected the first person outside the loop, and you don't want to include that guy in your sampling frame for the second person. This may explain why you get duplicates.
simulate <- function(n) {
  S <- 1:n
  L <- sample(S, 1)
  result <- L
  
  for (i in 2:(n-1)) {
    # Remove the previous person from the sampling frame
    S <- S[S != L]
    probabilities <- sapply(S, function(x) calculate_probability(S, L, x))
    L <- sample(S, 1, prob = probabilities)
    result <- c(result, L)
  }
  
  # The last guy must be selected with certainty
  result <- c(result, setdiff(1:n, result))
  
  return(result)
}


result <- simulate(100)

any(duplicated(result))
[1] FALSE


Here is an attempt to simulate the random ordering using an elimination process via a loop:
library(ggplot2)


calculate_probability <- function(S, L, x) {
    S <- S[S != L]
    
    if (!(x %in% S)) {
        return(0)
    }
    
    numerator <- 1 / (abs(x - L) + 1)
    denominator <- sum(1 / (abs(S - L) + 1))
    probability <- numerator / denominator
    
    return(probability)
}


simulate <- function(n) {
    S <- c(1:n)
    L <- sample(S, 1)
    result <- c(L)
    
    for (i in 2:n) {
        probabilities <- sapply(S, function(x) calculate_probability(S, L, x))
        L <- sample(S, 1, prob = probabilities)
        result <- c(result, L)
        S <- S[S != L]
    }
    
    return(result)
}

result <- simulate(100)


df <- data.frame(index = 1:100, person = result)
ggplot(df, aes(x = index, y = person)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Index", y = "Person") +
    theme_minimal()

enter image description here
However, there seems to be duplicates here, suggesting that the random ordering is not correct:
 result[duplicated(result) | duplicated(result, fromLast = TRUE)]
[1] 25 25


Welcome to Stackoverflow. Generally you'd state your problem, as you did above, show what you've tried so far, which you did, partly, above, and reach your further problem, that in this case is your answer, that still has a problem in your view. I suggest you merge your question and answer into a question, as your 'However' says you haven't arrived at an answer.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
